# My app crash after i press "Log in with Facebook" React-native fbsdk

Tags: facebook, authentication, react-native

i tried to integrate my app with facebook like this:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
    GraphRequest,
    GraphRequestManager,
    AccessToken,
    LoginButton,
    LoginManager
} = FBSDK;
```

....

```
        <LoginButton
            style={styles.facebookRegButton}
            readPermissions={['public_profile']}
            onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")} />
```

now when i press on the facebook login button my app crash with the error:
"appname stopped".

i working with android

this is my mainActivity.java file:

```
package com.students;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    CallbackManager mCallbackManager = MainApplication.getCallbackManager();
    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "students";
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

and MainApplication.java file:

```
package com.students;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager =
    CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
          new ImagePickerPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

My react native version is: 0.36.1

tnx a lot

Comment: Are you able to use Android Studio to look at the logs? you might be able to get a more detailed error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't must edit `MainActivity.java` only `MainApplication.java`.

To solve it:

1. MainActivity.java to default
2. You must configure `strings.xml`. That file is in `android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml`. Write this line inside `<resources>` tag.

   `<string name="facebook_app_id">IDFACEBOOKAPP</string>`

   Put your facebook app id inside.